# Why is the sample() function, that i am using to populate a variable, not regenerating the said variable

Tags: r

Originally this post was about using excess randomness and finding a mode(maximum frequency) in a matrix named list_14300.  Then another aspect of the programming started to bother me, each time I run the code below under A). then close R and restart R and run the same code the user defined function ,estimate_mode, gives me the same output.  This is annoying, I am expecting a different output each time.  Does this have to do with not saving before I exit, if so does that mean that each time output is not random.

Here is a function I found on stackoverflow that finds mode of a vector or matrix:

```
estimate_mode <- function(x) {
  d <- density(x)
  d$x[which.max(d$y)]
}
```

Below I am creating a 1430 by 10 matrix(list_14300) and then with the above function, determine which value in that matrix (between 1:1430) occurs with most frequency in the matrix with 14300 values.

A).

```
list_14300<-replicate(10,sample(1:1430,1430,replace = TRUE))

estimate_mode(list_14300)
```

Every time I run the code below and close the R program and reopen R and then run the same code WHY do i get the same output.  I expect random sampling and thus distinct results.  This is what I am running:

```
list_14300<-replicate(10,sample(1:1430,1430,replace = TRUE))
#### MODE
estimate_mode(list_14300)
#

list_14300[1430,]
min(list_14300[1430,])
max(list_14300[1430,])
list_14300[1430,1]
#
```

And every time I am closing and reopening R and run the code above this result is given back again:

```
> list_14300<-replicate(10,sample(1:1430,1430,replace = TRUE))
> #### MODE
> estimate_mode(list_14300)
[1] 459.4862
> #
> 
> list_14300[1430,]
[1] 1011  369  841 1383   82 1317  768  343  998 1203
> min(list_14300[1430,])
[1] 82
> max(list_14300[1430,])
[1] 1383
> list_14300[1430,1]
[1] 1011
```

WHY THE HECK ARE NOT RESULTS DISTINCT EACH TIME, AS I EXPECT?

Comment: what is `list_1430` ? you refer to it as the argument of `length()` in the definition of `list_14300`

Comment: Your `list_14300` definition won't run because it depends on `list_1430` (typo? should this also be `list_14300`?) which isn't defined. Also, I would recommend against naming a `matrix` with `list` since a `list` is something different.

Comment: But in general, `apply` works well for matrices. `apply(your_matrix, MARGIN = 1, estimate_mode)` will apply the `estimate_mode` function to each row of the matrix. Use `MARGIN = 2` for columns instead.

Comment: Thanks y'all.  Yeah, sorry list_1440 was simply as a vector 1:1430, thus replacing it with 1430 with list_1430 is the appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have changed the scope of the question considerably after I posted my answer, the answer is for the initial question you had posted.

If I understand you correctly, then you can create a list with each element being a matrix of dimension 1430 x 10:

```
a <- list()
for(i in 1:100) {a[[i]] <- replicate(10, sample(1:1430, 1430), replace = TRUE))}
```

You can check the second matrix for example like this:

```
   a[[2]]
```

Then to find which number occurs most frequently in each matrix, we write this function:

```
GetMax <- function(x){
                     counts <- table(x)
                     counts_max <- as.numeric(names(counts[which.max(counts)]))
                     return(counts_max)
                     }
```

Then, we can apply to all 100 matrices:

```
lapply(a, GetMax)
```

You can instead get the results in a vector and plot a histogram:

```
most_freq <- unlist(lapply(a, GetMax))
hist(most_freq)
```